# CSS Table: bottom borders that don't touch and rounded corners

Tags: html, css, html-table

Here's the fiddle for what I'm working on:

http://jsfiddle.net/rSUhL/

I'm trying to replicate this image:

[image: http://unbouncepages-com.s3.amazonaws.com/www.mastermindtalks.com/d9bpvf-mastermindmindset.png]

I'm pretty close. But for some reason, when I add border-radius to the table, it doesn't round the corners.

Also, is it possible to make it so the bottom-border doesn't touch the side of the boxes?

Here's the CSS:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size: 18px;
}

th, td {
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 25px;
}

th {
    text-align: right;
}

#blank {
    border: none;
}

caption {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.blue {
    background-color: #2a9ce0;
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #55ace0;
}

.small-text {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
<caption>Is Mastermind Talks for you?</caption>
<tr>
    <th scope="row">Learning:</th>
    <td>Tabloids and Newspapers</td>
    <td class="blue">Books, blogs, seminars and peers</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th scope="row">Focus:</th>
    <td>Hourly or Salary</td>
    <td class="blue">Cashflow, net worth and network</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th scope="row">Financial Goals:</th>
    <td>To survive until the next payday</td>
    <td class="blue">To build passive income streams</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th scope="row">Rate of Return:</th>
    <td>Get Rich Quick</td>
    <td class="blue">Long-term</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th scope="row">Investments:</th>
    <td>Liabilities: Cars, houses, etc</td>
    <td class="blue">Assets: Yourself, business, etc</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th scope="row">Values:</th>
    <td>Currency</td>
    <td class="blue">Legacy</td>
</tr>
<tfoot>
    <td id="blank"></td>
    <td><strong>Middle Class Mindset</strong><br /> <span class="small-text">(mastermind is not for you)</span></td>
        <td class="blue"><i class="icon-bulb"></i><strong>Mastermind Mindset</strong><br /> <span class="small-text">(mastermind is for you)</span></td>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: If you found any of the answers helpful, do you mind marking an accepted answer? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The `border-radius` declaration does not work with table border if the `border-collapse` is set to `collapse`. You have to define your borders on the `td` elements for border radius to work in this case.

Or, you can use `border-collapse: separate;` for border radius to work on the table itself.

Answer (score 0):

Change the class name of

```
 <td class="blue">Books, blogs, seminars and peers</td>
```

and

```
<td class="blue"><i class="icon-bulb"></i><strong>Mastermind Mindset</strong><br /> <span class="small-text">(mastermind is for you)</span></td>
```

to

```
<td class="blue1">Books, blogs, seminars and peers</td>
<td class="blue2"><i class="icon-bulb"></i><strong>Mastermind Mindset</strong><br /> <span class="small-text">(mastermind is for you)</span></td>
```

Then add the classes in CSS:

```
.blue1{
  border-radius:8px 8px 0px 0px !important;
  background-color: #2a9ce0;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #55ace0; 
}

.blue2{
  border-radius:0px 0px 8px 8px !important;
  background-color: #2a9ce0;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #55ace0;
 }
```